# Wp mail does not work when Ajaxed to

Tags: ajax, wp-mail

I tried to including wp-load, but the wp mail refuses to work when it is called from an ajax hooked function. How can I work around this? Also, on another note, the parameters I sent through AJAX to php don't get sent the same way if they have certain punctuation in them. Specifying the encoding didn't help.

```
// works when run on a template, but wp_mail doesn't work
// when called from a php file that I ajax to
book_schedule('18', '16', '1437609600', 22, 840);

function book_schedule(..., ..., ..., ..., ...){
    // php mail always gets sent
    mail('my_email@gmail.com', 'new message', 'tried once more');

    // wp mail does not
    wp_mail('my_email@gmail.com', 'new message', 'tried with WP');
}
```

Comment: with WordPress you don't need to create a PHP file for AJAX. read this : https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Are you using the [AJAX API](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)? If not, you are most likely doing it wrong.

Comment: @s_ha_dum It's changed to AJAX API, but the parameters passed in are not interpreted.(the email address or anything with certain punctuation) And wp-mail also doesn't work while php mail does.